# ORA-01722: invalid number #time

Tags: sql, oracle, time

I am running the below mentioned query in my Oracle and I am getting `ORA-01722: invalid number #time`.

```
  select *
  from time_checker
  where to_char(time,'HH24:MI')
    not between to_char('01:00','HH24:MI') and to_char('02:30','HH24:MI');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct version of the query is

```
select * from time_checker where time not between 
  to_date('01:00','HH24:MI') and to_date('02:30','HH24:MI');
```

Here `time` is the field you are checking. So ideally you must convert the parameters '01:00' etc to the datatype of the column `time`.

If `time` column is of type `timestamp`, then use `to_timestamp`.

Comment: actually I don't want to select time between (01:00) and (2:30) through select statement but problem is that (1:00) and (2:30) also not selected.

Answer (score 0):

`to_char (n, fmt)` converts n to a value of VARCHAR2 datatype, using the format `fmt`: [docs](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions181.htm).

Maybe you should use [to_date](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions183.htm).

Comment: @Mirwais Faizi What type has a time column?